# Run-time error '438' Format rows based on IndentLevel

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a requirements document with nested requirement lines and want to format the text based on the indent level of text in column B.

This is my first attempt at a Macro and I attempted not defining the Worksheet, removed all Dims, attempted just running the Select Case portion, but received various other errors.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Set ws = Sheet1("Sheet1")
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow

    Select Case Range("B").IndentLevel
    Case 0
        ws.Range("B").Font.Bold = True
    Case 1
        ws.Range("B").Font.ColorIndex = 5
        ws.Range("B").Font.Bold = False

    End Select

Next
End Sub
```

Expected result is to have not intent create a bolded font, intent 1 colored font that is not bold.

Comment: Change every `Range("B")` to `Range("B" & i)`

Comment: also `Sheet1("Sheet1")` should be `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: Also `Range("B" & i)` should be `ws.Range("B" & i)`